# Device crashes sometimes - Overlaying UINavigationController view with subview

Tags: ios, autolayout

So this is what I'm doing. I need the modal card view I'm pulling up to overlay the navigation bar.

[image: Overlay]

To do this I'm adding an overlay and the card view to the navigation controller view:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_answerDetailOverlay];
[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:_answerDetailOverlay];
```

This works great most of the time. In fact it never crashed the simulator. On the device though, I occasionally get a crash. I either get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in `-[NSLayoutConstraint _engineToContainerScalingCoefficients] + 48` or `Unable to parse constraint format: Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview |-[_answerDetailView]-| ^`.

Not sure if there is a better way to be doing this. Maybe adding to window instead?

Comment: You should avoid like the plague using the navigator's view - its really not suppose to be used for anything. Try getting the topViewController's view, and add it there.

Comment: Window seems to work as well. Noted thanks.